# How to setup an Express Gateway proxy with CAS authentication

Tags: cas, api-gateway, express-gateway

I'm trying to build a proof-of-concept API gateway to aggregate and centralize several tools exposed via APIs.

Express Gateway fits the bill perfectly for my use case, however I'm not entirely sure how to setup the proxy policy with a CAS (or even if it's possible yet).

The tools I want to aggregate are behind a CAS, so when I try to re-route the requests they fail.

Is it possible to use Express Gateway in such a way?

Maybe I would need to manually setup the headers to be passed through or manually hook up the Basic Authentication policy somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking there's nothing preventing the two systems to work together correctly.

I'm not so familiar with `CAS` itself, but I would expect them to have some sort of SDK (maybe a WebAPI?) that you can use to write your own integration.

In that case, you can then write an [Express Gateway plugin](https://express-gateway.io/docs/plugins) to integrate such feature with the gateway itself.

Try to have a look to our plugin documentation; then I'd invite you to stop by on our Gitter channel where we could in case have a real time discussion on the thing.

Cheers,

V.

Comment: I was wondering if the plugin was already in the works. 

It seems like the CAS protocol is not that complex (https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html) so I'll see if I can implement something. 

Just wanted to make sure this was not a trivial option or setting that I could turn on. Thanks! :)

Comment: We do not have any builtin policy that can do that. You can reuse any you can find around.